# Existing k8s targets failing to connect after octopus upgrade

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, octopus-deploy

We have just upgraded our octopus deploy instance from 2019.13.X to 2020.3.4

Before we had several k8s (Azure AKS) targets configured using Azure Service Principal, all doing fine for ages. After the upgrade all k8s targets are now failing to connect with the following message:

`Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp [::1]:8080: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it:`

We are using kubectl 1.18.16 on client (Octopus) and 1.17.9 in the cluster.

Additionally, we have validating that it works with a custom kube config (from local) according to this: https://octopus.com/docs/infrastructure/deployment-targets/kubernetes-target#debugging

This reveals that Octopus is building a config like this:

```
apiVersion: v1 
clusters: null 
contexts: 
- context: 
    cluster: "" 
    namespace: stag 
    user: "" 
  name: aks-istio-test 
current-context: "" 
kind: Config 
preferences: {} 
users: null
```

That is obviously not working.
The article doesn't specify how to continue if this debug script actually fails.

So my question is, what is going on here? How should we progress?

Comment: Also found this help article without any real resolution options: https://help.octopus.com/t/kubectl-unable-to-connect-to-the-server-dial-tcp-1-connectex-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it/22806

Comment: Hi Hulvej, have you contacted support@octopus.com? They can help with troubleshooting steps.